# Python ssl socket server SSLV3_ALERT_CERTIFICATE_UNKNOWN issue

Tags: python, sockets, ssl, tcp, server

I am writing a python socket server with ssl and I am encountering certificate unknown error during ssl handshake.

I have created private key and certificate with `openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365 -nodes` command on my own.
This server is intended to run in intranet(under wifi) in my PC, and users will contact my PC IPaddress with their browser. Hence I have not registered this certificate with any CA. and I don't think its mandatory in my case.
Below more details..

**echoserver.py**

```py
import socket
import ssl
import threading
class echoserver:
    def __init__(self,i,p):
        self.ip=i
        self.port=p
    def handler(self,c,a):
        msg=c.recv(1024)
        c.send(msg)
    def serve(self):
        echoserver = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        echoserver = ssl.wrap_socket(echoserver, keyfile='keys/key.pem', certfile='keys/cert.pem', server_side=True)
        echoserver.bind((self.ip, self.port))
        echoserver.listen()
        while True:
            (c,a)=echoserver.accept()
            threading.Thread(target=self.handler, args=(c,a)).start()

es=echoserver('192.168.43.124',443) #My PC's ip assigned under wifi network
es.serve()

#Connecting from mobile phone within same network as https://192.163.43.124
```

**Error in server during ssl handshake**

```
        self._sslobj.do_handshake()      
    ssl.SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_CERTIFICATE_UNKNOWN] sslv3 alert certificate unknown (_ssl.c:1108)
```

**What I tried**

- Adding cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_NONE and ca_certs="/location/to/keys" parameters in wrap_socket function.
  Doesn't seems to work. I assume these options are for client side.
- Adding do_handshake_on_connect=False in wrap_socket function
  In Chrome, When connected server throws same error and thread/connection closed with exception. and **chrome seems to send same connection request immediately again**, and the second request works flawlessly !!.
  In firefox, First connection closed with same error and there is no second request.
- Assigning common name in certificate same as IP address
  Not working.
- Checked certificate_unknown error in ietf specification [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446). It gives no clue except this explanation    `certificate_unknown:  Some other (unspecified) issue arose in processing the certificate, rendering it unacceptable.`

**One other thing I noted is**, if I use built-in `ThreadedHTTPServer` in the same way as below, It works beautifully, without any issues I mentioned above.

```py
httpd = self.ThreadedHTTPServer((self.ip, self.port), self.handler)
httpd.socket = ssl.wrap_socket(httpd.socket, keyfile='keys/key.pem', certfile='keys/cert.pem', server_side=True)
```

I am not sure why this happens and how should I proceed with this. and not sure how built-in server modules works fine.

Appreciate any leads. Thanks.

**Below Python builtin HTTPServer works fine with ssl, not showing any error. Not sure how?**

```py
import ssl
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler

class requesthandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type","text/html")
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write("<html><body>It works</body></html>".encode('utf8'))

httpd = HTTPServer(('192.168.43.124', 443), requesthandler)
httpd.socket = ssl.wrap_socket(httpd.socket, keyfile='keys/key.pem', certfile='keys/cert.pem', server_side=True)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> ssl.SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_CERTIFICATE_UNKNOWN] sslv3 alert certificate unknown (_ssl.c:1108)
> ```

This means the client (browser) does not trust your certificate since it is issued by an unknown entity. If you want to use self-signed certificates you have to explicitly import these as trusted for all clients you want to use.

There is no way around this. The certificate in TLS is to make sure that the connection is done with the expected server and not some man in the middle claiming to be the expected server. If a client would trust arbitrary certificates then it would also trust certificates created by a man in the middle attacker.

> Below Python builtin HTTPServer works fine with ssl, not showing any error. Not sure how?

The browser will still complain.
The only difference is that the server captures the exception and thus will not crash but continue. You can do the same in your code:

```
    while True:
        try:
            (c,a)=echoserver.accept()
            threading.Thread(target=self.handler, args=(c,a)).start()
        except:
            pass # ignore error
```

Comment: Thanks @Steffen. Appreciated.Can you explain, how this work fine for builtin server modules such ThreadedHTTPServer.

Comment: @Liju: It should not work with a self-signed certificate and ThreadedHTTPServer either unless you've explicitly  skipped the security warning in the browser.

Comment: Thanks @Steffen. I am re-phrasing my question. as a test,I tried creating a new ThreadedHTTPServer instance and ssl_wrapped it with same keys and started it in PC. Now I can connect from mobile browser. There was no certificate error thrown in server (sent by browser). And that's what I am wondering how? Is it designed to suppress and ignore these errors from browser somehow and continue?

Comment: @Liju: No you cannot suppress the errors from the server, this would be a huge security problem. Could you please provide the code and certificate so that I could reproduce it myself?

Comment: Thanks @Steffen. Appreciate.  I have updated the post with the code that is working fine along with keys. Code that is not working is the very first program in this post, same keys.

Comment: @Liju: I get a clear `NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID'` in the browser - as expected. The only thing which is different is that the server does not crash since the class you use captures the error. Still, the problem is the same in that the certificate is not trusted by the client. One need to explicitly skip the warning in order to access the content.

Comment: Yes. Browser side, if i click "accept the risk" it proceeds. But server side, How python builtin HTTPServer continues to work even after it captures the error but my socket program terminates.? May be Im missing a very basic thing. Could you explain how can I achieve that error tolerance in server side.